# I seem to get a null when my code runs

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class PigLatins {    
    String str1;
    int vowelIndex;
    String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"};
    String  counter = "";

    public String pigLatin(String str) {
        String[] result = str.split("\\s");

         for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
                for(int i = 0;i<vowels[i].length();i++) {               
                    if(!result[x].contains(vowels[i])) {
                        str1 = result[x]+"ay";
                    }                       
                    else if(result[x].startsWith(vowels[i])) {
                        str1 = result[x]+"ay";
                    }
                    for(int j = 0;j<result[x].length();j++) 
                        if(Character.toString(result[x].charAt(j)) == vowels[i]) {
                            vowelIndex = j;
                            break;
                        }

                    if(vowelIndex > 0 && !result[x].startsWith(vowels[i]) &&     result[x].contains(vowels[i])) {
                        str1 = result[x].substring(1,vowelIndex) +        result[x].substring(0,1) + "ay";
                        }                           
                }       
            counter+=str1;  
         }       
         return counter;             
    }

}
```

At this part `result[x].substring(1,vowelIndex)` in the if statement, it seems to return null, why is it wrong and how could I fix it? (I removed the driver class as stackoverflow told me to I had too much code)

Comment: might be because you do substring that start at place 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Never paraphrase error messages. It matters here whether the exact exception is `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: can you provide an input that cause the exception?

Comment: sorry it's StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, i'm starting the substring at 1 on purpose, and im using "hasta la vista baby!"

Comment: If you used a debugger, you could find out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should change :

```
for(int i = 0;i<vowels[i].length();i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0;i<vowels.length;i++)
```

Since you want to iterate over all the vowels in the array.

`vowels[i].length()` will always give you 1, since it's the length of the i'th String in the vowels array.

Beside that, it would make more sense to change the vowels array from String[] to char[].

Comment: vowels is an array though

Comment: @RobinChang But when you access its length, you access the length of the **whole** array, not the length of just the first item.

Comment: now I get a cannot find symbol error since vowels[] and vowels are different things correct me if im wrong

Comment: @RobinChang What code gives you the error and what symbol cannot be found?

Comment: when i change the vowels[] to vowels, and I'm assuming the variable vowels cannot be found

Comment: @RobinChang Did you test this? You have a `vowels` variable. It's an array. An array has a length property. Therefore vowels.length should work.

Comment: yes, I believe i did

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that the `vowelIndex` is 0 while you start in index 1 for the substring.

i don't quite understand what you are trying to achive but you need to check in you if statement the value of `vowelIndex`:

```
if(vowelIndex > 0 && !result[x].startsWith(vowels[i]) && result[x].contains(vowels[i]))
```

the whole function should be

```
public String pigLatin(String str) {
    String[] result = str.split("\\s");

         for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
                for(int i = 0;i<vowels[i].length();i++) {               
                    if(!result[x].contains(vowels[i])) {
                        str1 = result[x]+"ay";
                    }                       
                    else if(result[x].startsWith(vowels[i])) {
                        str1 = result[x]+"ay";
                    }
                    for(int j = 0;j<result[x].length();j++) 
                        if(Character.toString(result[x].charAt(j)) == vowels[i]) {
                            vowelIndex = j;
                            break;
                        }

                    if(vowelIndex > 0 && !result[x].startsWith(vowels[i]) && result[x].contains(vowels[i])) {
                        str1 = result[x].substring(1,vowelIndex) + result[x].substring(0,1) + "ay";
                        }                           
                }       
            counter+=str1;  
         }       
         return counter;             
}
```

also you should not use an array of strings of you need an array of charecters, or if i understand correctly you should use a set of charecters

Comment: @RobinChang give me an input

Comment: currently im using "hasta la vista baby!"

Comment: ran it with this code and got output
"asklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxdayasklkgrmvxday"

Comment: @RobinChang read the prev comment. i got no exception

Comment: in this line of code str1 = result[x].substring(1,vowelIndex) + result[x].substring(0,1) + "ay"; if i were to remove result[x].substring(1,vowelIndex) then it would run as how it should

Comment: additionally when I tested your code, it returned nullnullnullnull

Comment: @RobinChang i have no idea what you do wrong. can you edit the question and add all of your code?

Comment: @RobinChang unfortunately from your code i can't understand how you activate it, and when i do it, the code run as expected.